# Performance of update operation on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, sql-update

I have to mention that I have two different SQL Server instances on two different servers.

1. Process; Server A is applying 300 - 400 insert command to the local database. About 1 second.
2. Process; A 300 - 400 update command is sent from server A to server B over IIS. This update process is done on the indexed primary key and takes an average of 4 seconds.

In the second transaction, I closed the transaction on IIS, I used the same transaction with the database link feature, but the result is still the same.
There is a trigger in the updated table on server B.
Server B has the update command for each line, so there is a command starting with 300-400 update.

My problems:

Why is the process taking a long time in transaction 2?
In the second process, what kind of points I need to pay attention to in the update query.

Comment: Using all-caps (even in the title), is the internet-equivalent of shouting. Please don't do that.

Comment: Need to know the update command (direct sql commands over network or API), if you use ORMs, the table structure (indexes and triggers), IIS configuration. There is a lot of information that we need to do some kind of suggestion.

Comment: The most likely reason is because "there is a trigger". Without code, it is impossible to guess. Don't know how you measure "4 seconds" but you need to account for network latency for the remote database to have an apples-to-applies comparison if you measure from the application.

Comment: For update statement performance, you can refer to:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5829/update-statement-performance-in-sql-server/